# Ajax and Django to get a multi-select smart panel to work dynamically

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-1.10, django-ajax-selects

Please any idea how i can achieve something like this with Ajax and Django.
Lets say a medical app. 
I'll like to multi-select medicine while it shows in a different panel and add the amount(s) sum and show me like the right text-boxes..

[image: AJax With Django]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using [`django-select2`](https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2) to get `select2` widget integration with Django. Then you can define your forms and views using the tools it has to offer.